# Tools for finding possible problems in code

Tags: java, code-analysis

Is there any tools, that find and report possible problems (deadlocks/null pointers/etc) in a java code? Maybe an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here are some popular, free and open source static code checking tools for Java:

- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

i use http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/ and it works very well. of course it won't find all problems but stuff like potential null pointers, potential synchronization issues etc are all covered. it comes as an eclipse plugin that integrates with the 'markers' view (the one that shows you problems)

Answer (score 0):

You could look on these too:

- [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html)
- Emma - For unit test coverage %
- Same - For check duplicated code